# Question about Wire Transfer

Tags: wire-transfer

I recently changed address, but have the same bank account details. My employer has sent the wire transfer to my account with all the information correct, but listed my old home address. Will this cause any problems?

Answer (score 2):

No. As long as the Account details and Bank details are correct, the transfer will go through fine.

The address is used to sanction screen before a payment is made. Generally address of certain band entities [terrorism, money laundering, etc] are listed and if there is a payment instruction with these address, it is scrutinized further.

It is however advisable to have the address corrected with your employer as soon as possible so that correct details are furnished.